# Custom StopWord List In SQL Server 2005 Full-Text-Search

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search, stop-words

Is there anyway to add some custom stop words to SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

**On SQL Server 2005:**
On SQL 2005 they have the concept of "noise word lists". These are essentially the same thing, but they're stored as text files in the file system. These files have names like "noiseenu.txt" (U.S. English noise word text file) and are located in a subdirectory of your SQL Server instance directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData\, for instance). You can edit it with any text editor and save again. I don't recall whether or not you need to bounce the service afterwards on 2005 (don't recall if the noiseword list is cached in memory, but you may as well bounce it to be sure). Then you have to rebuild your full-text indexes.

**On SQL Server 2008:**
You can create a custom stopword list on SQL 2008 the server will remove the stopwords at index time and when it parses your full-text search queries. All you have to do is specify that your full-text index use the custom stoplist.

Comment: Just to expand desmati's answer slightly. SQL2008 can have multiple stoplists defined for it, which means you have have a different stop list on each full-text index (i.e. each table with an fts index can use its own stoplist)